# Bitcoind JSON RPC auth not working

Tags: json, rpc, bitcoin

I have runing bitcoind on ubuntu. bitcoin-cli works fine. I can not get working json rpc protocol

bitcoin.conf file:

```
testnet=0
rpcuser="bitcoinrpc"
rpcpassword="xxxxx"
rpcport=8332
rpcallowip="*"
server=1
```

http post request with url='http://bitcoinrpc:xxxxx@127.0.0.1:8332/' fails with 401 error.

request headers:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6,de;q=0.4,sr;q=0.2
Authorization:Basic Yml0Y29pbnJwYzp4eHh4eA==
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:53
Content-Type:text/plain
DNT:1
Host:127.0.0.1:8332
Origin:chrome-extension://fhjcajmcbmldlhcimfajhfbgofnpcjmb
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/51.0.2704.79 Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36
```

request post payload:

```
{jsonrpc: "2.0", method: "getinfo", params: []}
```

What is correct way for bitcoind json rpc autentification?

Comment: Are you connecting from localhost or from an external machine? If you connect from the local machine, try `rpcallowip=127.0.0.1`. If you connect from an external machine, try `rpcallowip=*`. Notice that I removed the `"` after `rpcallowip`.

Comment: Thank you. Problem was in config file path. bitcoind takes it from home directory. My problem was  what i put it in data directory.

Answer (score 0):

For future googlers: a possible problem is that the password should not contain the pound sign (`#`) as this is treated as a comment!